# how to set different languages

Tags: android

I want my app to use the italian version of the strings.xml if the user's device is set to italian language, otherwise i want my app to use the default strings.xml with english text.

i did this

```
res/values/strings.xml <--- english

res/values/values-it/strings.xml <--- italian //THIS WAS MY ERROR
```

According to Google guide http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html i don't have to do anything! Android will do all the work!
But when i try to run the app on my device (set to italian language), my app keep on "speaking" english.

What should i do?

I changed it this way, and now it works.

```
res/values/strings.xml <--- english

res/values-it/strings.xml <--- italian
```

Comment: You sure that the string ID's are the same in the files. Could you show some string from both xml files

Comment: I put values-it/strings.xml inside res/values. Now i have res/values and res/values-it, and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings have to be organized like this:

```
res/values/strings.xml

res/values-it/strings.xml
```

Comment: This was my error!  I put `values-it/strings.xml` inside `res/values`.
Now i have  `res/values` and `res/values-it`, and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
  String s = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
  if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("italiano"))
     {
        Resources res = getResources();
        Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        newConfig.locale = new Locale("it", "IT");
        res.updateConfiguration(newConfig, null);
     }
```

Comment: Mmm it doens't work. With `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();` i get "italiano", so i'm sure android knows i have italian on my device.
Of course i turned `if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("italian"))` into `if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("italiano"))` but nothing happens. I'm using 2 device (galaxy s2 and a samsung tablet) but it neither work on the mobile nor on the tablet

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali : Are u setting text correctly in the textView??

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get it :(

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali : Can u post the code where you are setting text to a textview?

Comment: I have two ways:
sometimes i did it inside the layout.xml
`<TextView            android:text="@string/infoVota"/>`
and sometimes i did it by using java 
`TextView cassaTextView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.cassaTextView);
   cassaTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cassaUltimaPartita));`

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali : When u are setting via code u have to set `textView.setText(R.string.infoVota);` Are u doing like that??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23834/discussion-between-deepzz-and-matteo-depasquali)

Comment: Sorry. i made a stupid mistake.  I put `values-it/strings.xml` inside `res/values`. Now i have `values` and `values-it` at the same level, and it works. It isne't even necessary the code java you provided me. 
I made you waste time making such a stupid error Thank you